# gjs/gnome-shell-extension: Updating button text every 60 seconds

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I want to write a simple gnome extension that prints some text on my top bar from a text file. I managed to print the text but i'm having trouble with updating it every 60 seconds. Is it even possible with gjs?

this is what i came up with:

```
const {St, Clutter} = imports.gi;
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;



let panelButton;

function init () {
// Create a Button with "Hello World" text
panelButton = new St.Bin({
    style_class : "panel-button",
});

let fileContents = String(GLib.file_get_contents("path/to/myfile.txt")[1]);

let panelButtonText = new St.Label({
    text : fileContents,
    y_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.CENTER,
});
panelButton.set_child(panelButtonText);
}

function enable () {
// Add the button to the panel
Main.panel._centerBox.insert_child_at_index(panelButton, 2);
}

function disable () {
// Remove the added button from panel
Main.panel._centerBox.remove_child(panelButton);
}
```

Comment: if not going deep into the Question. there is a extension already. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659786/383311

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use [`GLib.timeout_add_seconds()`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/glib20%7E2.66.1/glib.timeout_add_seconds):

```
GLib.timeout_add_seconds(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 60, () => {
   updateLabel(newText);
   return GLib.SOURCE_CONTINUE;
});
```

By the way, you should probably use `ByteArray.toString()` to convert the Uint8Array that you get from the file into a string.

Comment: This isn't working for me, and its driving me insane. Please check the below snippet: the timeout code runs the first time, but never afterwards ever.
```
function init() {
    _extensionButton = new PanelMenu.Button(0.0, 'temp', false);
    let panelButtonText = new St.Label({
        text: "5/8",
        y_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.CENTER,
    });
    _extensionButton.add_child(panelButtonText);
    GLib.timeout_add_seconds(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 3, () => {
        log('Doesnt work' + String(i));
        panelButtonText.set_text(String(i))
        i += 3;
    });
}
```

Comment: I forgot `GLib.SOURCE_CONTINUE`. Please see the edit

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you ... You dont realise how much I've been looking into why my `timeout_add_seconds` implementation never really ran the second time ... Thank you once more. Its so infuriating that such common stuff isnt documented in GNOME or GJS docs ..

Comment: It is documented, though it's easy to miss: "The function is called repeatedly until it returns `false`" (in JS, returning `undefined` is a falsey value)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have your extension [approved by ego](https://gjs.guide/extensions/review-guidelines/review-guidelines.html#destroy-all-objects) you'd possibly want to do it more like this (destroy in disable what you create in enable):

in `extension.js`:

```
let timeout = null;
```

in `function enable()`:

```
    timeout = GLib.timeout_add(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, (60 * 1000), () => {
        // ...do the right thing...
        return GLib.SOURCE_CONTINUE;
    });
```

in `function disable()`:

```
    if (timeout) {
        GLib.Source.remove(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }
```